# onload function js

Tags: javascript

I have onclick function

`if ($this->board['enablecaptcha'] ==  1) {
            $madness='<div id="lok" onclick="capture_ld()"><a onclick="capture_ld();">Введите капчу</a> </div>';`

I need something like

`if ($this->board['enablecaptcha'] ==  1) {
            $madness='<div id="lok" onload="capture_ld()"><a onload="capture_ld();">Введите капчу</a> </div>';`

But `<a onload=""` doesn't work. Help please

Comment: Can you describe what behavior you want for the div "lok"?

Comment: @MeowMix This div should load the captcha when page is loaded

Comment: Then you should follow PSR's advice. That should work for you.

Comment: Well, i can't use <body> tag because page will break. Any alternatives how i can load "capture_ld();" without onload function?

Comment: Well, you need an event handler for "onload" so you can do stuff, in this case "capture_id()". You should be able to add it to the JS file that "capture_id()" is residing in. Like @Francois' answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use onload for body tag

```
<body onload="capture_ld();">
</body>
```

or use

```
 <script>
capture_ld();
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, `<img>` tags and `<iframe>` tags have an onload event.  You certainly cannot use it with an `<a>` tag like the OP was trying.

Answer (score 0):

> This div should load the captcha when page is loaded

You could use [**window.onload**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload)

```
window.onload = function(){
    capture_ld();
};
```

The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

Comment: Wahl
Yeah, thanks! Now it's look like

` if ($this->board['enablecaptcha'] ==  1) {
   $madness='<div id="lok" onload="capture_ld()">
<script> window.onload = function(){
    capture_ld();
};
</script>
</div>';`

Comment: @user2175917: You can remove the in-line `onload="..."` from the other elements as well then. Did this work for you now?